# Spark streaming job exited abruptly - RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-standalone

The running spark streaming job, which is supposed to run continuously, exited abruptly with the following error (found in the executor logs):

```
2017-07-28 00:19:38,807 [SIGTERM handler] ERROR org.apache.spark.util.SignalUtils$$anonfun$registerLogger$1$$anonfun$apply$1 (SignalUtils.scala:43) - RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
```

The spark streaming job ran for ~62 hours before receiving this signal.

I couldn't find any other ERROR/ WARN in the executor logs. Unfortunately I haven't set up the driver logs yet, so I am not able to check on this specific issue deeper.

I am using Spark cluster in Standalone mode.

Any reason why driver might send this signal? (after spark streaming ran well and good for more than 60 hours)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?